# Fixed point method where the derivative is one - does it converge

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I'm trying to see if the iterative method $x_n=g(x_{n-1})$ where $g(x)=2\sqrt{x-1}$ will converge to $2$, if I take $x_0$ that is sufficiently close to $2$.

Indeed notice that $g(2)=2$. and we have a theorem that states that if $|g'(2)|<1$ then there is a neighborhood of $2$ such that if we take an $x_0$ from that neighborhood, the method will converge to $2$.

We also know that if $|g'(2)|>1$ then there is no such neighborhood.

But notice now that $g'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$, and so $g'(2)=1$.

What can we say about this situation? will it converge?

Comment: That should diverge, the absolute value needs to be less than 1.

Comment: @bobbym, that's only a sufficient condition for convergence.  Oria, try looking at a plot of the function.  It converges if $2 \leq x_0 < 2+\epsilon$ but diverges if $2-\epsilon < x_0 < 2$.

Comment: I think you are correct. if we take a number that is very very close to $2$, but smaller than $2$, than the derivative will be larger than one. There can be no neighborhood of $2$, since any value smaller than $2$ will yield derivative larger than 1

Comment: Isn't it mandatory for convergence Antonio?

Comment: No, take the system given by $g(x) = 2 + (x-2) - (x-2)^3$.  Here $g'(2) = 1$ but the dynamical system converges in a neighborhood of $x=2$.  If $|g'(x_\infty)| = 1$ it usually only means that the first derivative doesn't give you enough information to determine whether the system converges or diverges.

Comment: It depends on $g$ (obviously). It can happen that there is convergence in a neighbourhood of a fixed point $x_f$ with $\lvert g'(x_f)\rvert = 1$, or divergence in an entire punctured neighbourhood, or, like here, that there is convergence on one side, and divergence on the other. It depends also on the values of $g'$ in neighbourhoods of $x_f$.

Comment: Is my argument for the "divergence on the other side" correct? when I say neighborhood, I meant on both sides. Is my argument a proof that the negative side diverges?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas yes, you are correct. Sorry for the miscalculation to all.

Comment: @OriaGruber, surely it's evidence for divergence but the argument needs to be fleshed out more.  A proof would involve at least showing that there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $x_0 \in (2-\epsilon,2)$ we have $g(x_0) < x_0$, then arguing for why this implies divergence.